# Create the 2D blurring matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convolution

I can apply a filter on an image `I` by the following code:

```
h = fspecial('gaussian',20,4);
blurred = conv2(I,h,'same');
```

The size of the image `I` is the same as of `blurred`, I want to write the process of convolution in matrix multiplication form i.e. `blurred=H*I(:)` so i tried the following:

```
 H=convmtx2(h,size(I));
 blurred=H*I(:);
```

but the size of `blurred` after reshaping will be larger than of  `I` because `convmtx2` return a full convolution matrix, How can i get a convolution matrix that will return only the central part not the full convolution.

Comment: Just curious if the solution provided here worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and off course i will check it when i have access to matlab

Comment: Oh that's okay, I thought a nudge won't be a bad idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
h = fspecial('gaussian',20,4);

H=convmtx2(h,size(I));

I_conv = reshape(H*I(:),size(h)+size(I)-1);
s1 = round(size(h,1)/2);
blurred = I_conv(s1+1:s1+size(I,1),s1+1:s1+size(I,2));
```

Comment: `b2=imfilter(I,h); err=blurred-b2; max(max(err))` the maximum difference is pretty small.